# I18nPluralPipe adding offset

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a multiselect dropdown and I want to pluralize the text as mentioned below.
I tried using [I18nPluralPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe) but not able to provide an offset of 1

```
ListItem = [Lion, Tiger, Cat, Fox]
Select 1 Item(Tiger) = "Tiger", 
Select 3 Item(Tiger, Cat, Fox) = "Tiger +3 Other"
```

"Tiger +3 Others" is wrong, instead I want "Tiger +2 Others" and that's where I need the offset.

You can try I18nPluralPipe in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzwxoi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just substract 1 from the length. In that way you get the correct number:

```
  <span *ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
    (+{{ toppings.value.length - 1 | i18nPlural: messageMapping }})
  </span>
```

Comment: That's really so simple. How did I miss it. Thanks Paul